# jQuery: Where to put semicolons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I learn jQuery mainly by studying code from other people.

I found this script http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/.

I've changed a bit so I got this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav li a').click(function() {

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' article';
            $('article').fadeOut('slow',loadContent);

        function loadContent() {
            $('article').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }

        function showNewContent() {
            $('article').fadeIn('slow');
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Now after many problems, I noticed the whole thing not to work, when I put a semicolon after "showNewContent())". Why does that happen?

My second Question is, why does he start the function "loadContent" only with "loadContent" but the function "showNewContent" with "showNewContent()" (with brackets)?

Comment: semi colons are for line breaks. You execute one command for every semi-colon you put. I guess jQuery is a bit confusing in this regard because you can chain things together.

Comment: I'm the guy who wrote the question. Firstly thanks to everyone who tried to help. I guess my problem was my browser cache, which seemed to need a deletion. So thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

It's a mistake. That line should be:

```
$('article').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent);
```

By the way, you don't need to pass that second parameter. Use this instead:

```
$('article').load(toLoad, showNewContent);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. By the way, do you know what '' was for?

Comment: @Fart: take a look at http://api.jquery.com/load/ . Basically, there are 3 parameters you can pass to `.load`: URL, data, and a callback. Since he had no data to send, he passed in an empty string. However, as stated above, that is not necessary. If you'll look at the jQuery docs, you'll see that those parameters are optional and can simply be omitted.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions:

1) The semicolon at the end of the line

```
$('article').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
```

Should have no impact on the code being rendered. When you say it's not working, what do you mean?

2) The difference between the two calls is he is providing one function as a delegate to be called, whereas the other actually executes the function and returns it's value to the caller. The code seems to be mistaken; that parameter should be a callback to execute, not a value itself.

```
 // This is a reference to the method. IE, this would be valid code:
 var someMethod = loadContent;
 someMethod();

 var someResult = showNewContent();
 // someResult in this case is 'undefined', not a reference to a function.
```

The code above can be rewritten like so:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $('nav li a').click(function()
     {
          var toLoad = $(this).attr('href') + ' article';

          $('article').fadeOut('slow', function()
          {
              $('article').load(toLoad,  '', function()
              {
                    $('article').fadeIn('slow');
              });
          });
     });
});
```

Your example of putting inline functions with names might be confusing the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to include a semicolon after a statement. So this:

```
$('article').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
```

Should be

```
$('article').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
```

You don't need them after declaring a function, though it won't break anything if they're not there.

As for the difference between showNewContent and showNewContent(), the earlier passes the function to the load event. The later passes the result of the function (in this case there is no return for showNewContent so it returns null) to the load event. If you want your function to run at load then you will use the showNewContent version.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from invalid syntax see @Joseph's answer. The issue you're having is with your understanding of how to use functions (your second question).

A function in JavaScript can be assigned to a variable just like any other value.  What you're doing by passing showNewContent (no parenthesis) around is you're actually passing a variable around.  The load and fadeOut methods will take a look at that variable you're passing to them and execute it.  Here's a simple example in JavaScript where we pass a function into another function.

```
var myFuncToPass = function () { alert('hi'); };
doStuff(myFuncToPass);

function doStuff(func)
{
  func();  // will do an alert
}
```

Hope that helps.